# Signed social network example

Tags: networking, graph, network-programming, networkx, social-networking

I'm looking for an example for s**igned- social- network** (up to 10 nodes).
In class, the teacher showd us the example about "Signed International Relations" (https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Patrick_Doreian/publication/277717102_Structural_Balance_and_Signed_International_Relations/links/5571aa2b08ae49af4a95f285.pdf)

So I need another idea (from the real world)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [ICON](https://icon.colorado.edu/#!/networks) database has several examples of signed networks. There is a small social network of 16 individuals from New Guinea, recorded in the 1950s, that almost fits your requirements. Why do you need <10 nodes?

Comment: Teacher's request. Thank you I'll take a look